# Sorting order items

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I've been trying lots of methods to achieve but none worked.
Please give me a hint how to to this.

I need to use a sort by sku on products that appear on an order print.

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order)
```

this is $order collection and a few lines below I have:

```
foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) { ... }
```

I need the sort to be applied on getAllItems before showing, obviously.

I hope I was clear enough, if not ask.

Answer (score 1):

you might have already solved, but I will answer this for people having the same problem:

```
$oItems = $oOrder->getItemsCollection()->addAttributeToSort('price_incl_tax', 'DESC');
  $aItems = array();
  foreach ($oItems as $oItem) {
      if (!$oItem->isDeleted()) {
          $aItems[] =  $oItem;
      }
  }
```

Hope this helps anyone.